# List all the situations when an array is not converted to a pointer to a single element?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

So far I have encountered 3 situations where array stays as an array:
(assume `int arr[3][4];`)

1. sizeof(arr) : gives the total size (not one element's)
2. &arr + 1: advances the address by total size
3. binding a reference to interior array in range for:

//

```
   for(const auto &row : arr)
       for(auto col : row)
           cout << col << endl;
```

Question: 
Does this exhaust all the situations where array is not converted to a pointer to a single element?
If not, is there a systematic way of deciding it?

Comment: Actually `&arr` give you a *pointer*. Using the address-of operator will *always* give you a pointer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg but the question is, a pointer to one element or a pointer to the entire array? As in the `&arr+1` in the example.

Comment: Wherever the standard doesn't say array-to-pointer conversions take place? Offhand, you missed `decltype`. Probably `reinterpret_cast` or something as well.

Comment: @MarkRansom In the scope of this question, does it matter?

Comment: @chris, I only found 4.2/1 in n3797 but that short paragraph seems not helping much.

Comment: A string literal used to initialize an array object is not converted to a pointer. For example, in `char s[] = "hello";`, `"hello"` is an expression of array type that's not converted to a pointer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, it matters. It doesn't decay, which was why it is one of the answers to the OP's question (which he provided himself). I find it also quite interesting, and important, because of the `(&arr)[1]` case. Numerically the addresses are likely identical, but the type of the resulting pointer is different. Because of indexing semantics the operator& case is related to the sizeof case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the cases where this conversion happens are covered by [expr]#8:

> Whenever a glvalue expression appears as an operand of an operator that expects a prvalue for that operand, the lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), or function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are applied to convert the expression to a prvalue.

All of the operators which can take `arr` expect a prvalue (or otherwise explicitly request this conversion), except for:

- unary `&`
- `sizeof`
- `++`
- `--`
- `alignof`
- `typeid`

(Note: this list might not be exhaustive, I will update it if someone points out other cases!)

Now, There are various possible cases where we can use `arr` and it is not the operand of any operator. Some of those cases perform the conversion and some don't. The ones that do perform the conversion are:

- using `arr` as a function argument but not matching a prototype parameter
- some cases of template type deduction
- deducing the return type of a lambda

Notably, the conversion is not performed by binding `arr` to a reference (this is what happens in the range-based for-loop).  This is covered by [dcl.init.ref]#5.   In the line `T &ref = arr;`, the `=` is not the assignment operator; it's part of the syntax for declarations.

Comment: `return arr` won't if the return type is a reference to the array.

Comment: Good answer, voted up. am still fumbling around in the standard checking for the mentioned case.

Comment: @chris Fixed. I was hasty when searching the standard; the `return arr;` I was looking at actually only applies to deducing the return type of a lambda, e.g. `auto x1 = [] { return arr; }`  - return type is pointer

Comment: As a function arg it will not decay if the formal param is a ref to arr, like with returning one. Both are examples for binding to a ref "behind your back".

Comment: @PeterSchneider fixed. I was looking at the section talking about arguments corresponding to `...`